# How to use user input with filter function in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a filter function that I would like to adapt to user input, but I don't really know how to do it. I'm fairly new to Knockout so I would appreciate some help with this.

When I click the filter button (see code below) i get this in the input area:

```
function observable() {
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        // Write
        // Ignore writes if the value hasn't changed
        if (observable.isDifferent(observable[observableLatestValue], arguments[0])) {
            observable.valueWillMutate();
            observable[observableLatestValue] = arguments[0];
            observable.valueHasMutated();
            return this; // Permits chained assignments
        } else {
            // Read
            ko.dependencyDetection.registerDependency(observable); // The caller only needs to be notified of changes if they did a "read" operation
            return observable[observableLatestValue];
        }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to write a value in the input area, click the button (for now, will use submit later) and have the search results filtered. The array employeeList is an observable array that is populated through an ajax call (the search function).

KO Code:

```
self.employeeList = ko.observableArray([]);
self.currentFilter = ko.observable();

self.filterEmpl = ko.computed(function () {
            if (!self.currentFilter()) {
                return self.employeeList();
            } else {
                return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.employeeList(), function (employee) {
                    return employee.DepartmentName == self.currentFilter();
                });
            }
        });

        self.filter = function (value) {
            self.currentFilter(value);

    } //filter
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Department" id="department" class="filterInput" data-bind="value: currentFilter" />
    <button data-bind="click: function () { filter(currentFilter) }">Filter</button>
    <br />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Office" class="filterInput" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Skills" class="filterInput lastInput" />
</form>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `filterEmpl` is a `ko.computed`. This means it automatically updates once one of the `observable` values it uses is updated.

In your case, it will update whenever either `self.employeeList` or `self.currentFilter` changes.

To try this out, type one of the `DepartmentNames` in the example below. Once you remove focus from the input, the `value` data-bind updates `currentFilter`, and `self.filterEmpl` is updated.

```js
var VM = function() {
  self.employeeList = ko.observableArray([
    { DepartmentName: "Test1", Name: "Employee 1" },
    { DepartmentName: "Test2", Name: "Employee 2" }
  ]);
  self.currentFilter = ko.observable();

  self.filterEmpl = ko.computed(function() {
    if (!self.currentFilter()) {
      return self.employeeList();
    } else {
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.employeeList(), function(employee) {
        return employee.DepartmentName == self.currentFilter();
      });
    }
  });


}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h2>Type "Test1" or "Test2" and blur focus to filter</h2>
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Department" data-bind="value: currentFilter" />
</form>

<h2>All employees:</h2>
<ul data-bind="foreach: employeeList">
  <li data-bind="text: Name"></li>
</ul>

<h2>Filtered employees:</h2>
<ul data-bind="foreach: filterEmpl">
  <li data-bind="text: Name"></li>
</ul>
```

Now, if you want to filter *only* when a button is pressed, you don't need the `ko.computed`. You define a second `ko.observableArray` and write to it from within the `filter` function. Note that you don't need to pass it any arguments; the viewmodel is already aware of the `currentFilter` value via the `value` binding.

```js
var VM = function() {
  self.employeeList = ko.observableArray([
    { DepartmentName: "Test1", Name: "Employee 1" },
    { DepartmentName: "Test2", Name: "Employee 2" }
  ]);
  self.currentFilter = ko.observable();

  self.filterEmpl = ko.observableArray(self.employeeList());
  
  self.filter = function() {
    var result = self.employeeList(),
        filter = self.currentFilter();
    
    if (filter) {
      result = ko.utils.arrayFilter(result, function(employee) {
        return employee.DepartmentName == filter;
      });
    }
    
    self.filterEmpl(result);
  };


}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h2>Type "Test1" or "Test2" and tap button to filter</h2>
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Department" data-bind="value: currentFilter" />
  <button data-bind="click: filter">filter</button>
</form>

<h2>All employees:</h2>
<ul data-bind="foreach: employeeList">
  <li data-bind="text: Name"></li>
</ul>

<h2>Filtered employees:</h2>
<ul data-bind="foreach: filterEmpl">
  <li data-bind="text: Name"></li>
</ul>
```

Personally, I like to use the `computed` approach. You can extend the observable using the `rateLimit` option if performance is limiting. Ultimately, it's mostly a UX decision.

---

P.S. The input you did get in the input area is knockout's definition of the `ko.observable` function. In your `<button>`, you pass `currentFilter` without getting its value using `currentFilter()`. In `filter`, you write this to `currentFilter` which is data-bound to the `<input>`. I figured it'd be more useful to explain the two approaches, but you still might want to know where the strange input came from...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Neither options seem to work for me though. I keep getting the error that filterEmpl is undefined, and I think it is referring to where it is bound to the ul, although in my case it is a template:


`<div class="container col col--12 col--first "  data-bind="template: { name: 'employee', foreach: employeeList }"></div>
        <div class="container col col--12 col--first "  data-bind="template: { name: 'employee', foreach: filterEmp }"></div>`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `filterEmpl`, with an `L` at the end? Pretty sure it's a syntax error...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. You mentioned using ajax to populate the list; you might want to show that part of the code as well...

Comment: Yes, it was a syntax error. Although now it runs the filterEmpl function when I do the search that populates the employeeList, meaning I get 2 identical lists.

Comment: I'll need to see some code to understand what you mean. The difference between "search" and "filter" isn't clear to me. Can you send a fiddle or edit your question with your current code?

Comment: Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SlyW/951554d4/3/

I have figured out the problem, though. I was trying to apply the filter to an html-element and not the property in the object.